# how to write java program that read 5 numbers and calculate how many numbers has value from 0-9

Tags: java, loops

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class good
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner variable = new Scanner(System.in);

    int i = 0, counter = 0, n = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        n = variable.nextInt();
    }
    if ((0 <= n) && (n <= 9)) {
        counter++;
    }
    System.out.println("the number of values enterd from 0-9 is    " + counter);
   }

}
```

I have no errors in my program but I'm not getting a right answer.  For example :

```
 ----jGRASP exec: java good

5
6
4
the number of values enterd from 0-9 is    0

 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

I shoud get "3" 
but I get "0"

Comment: because your loop (`for(i=0;i<5;i++)`) is only looping the line immediately under it, which does not include the `if` statement. Do not omit the curly braces.

Comment: Where does your `for` loop end and where should it end?

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger and single step through the program. You will immediately see whats wrong.

Comment: @maria You just got help. Lots of it.

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't work because you are missing brackets on your for loop. You just execute `n=variable.nextInt()` five times without checking it, and then check it. If you include brackets this should work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use braces around your the inner for loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class good
    {
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {

    Scanner variable=new Scanner(System.in);

    int i=0,counter=0,n=0;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
       n=variable.nextInt();
       if((0<=n)&&(n<=9))
       counter++;
    }
    System.out.println("the number of values enterd from 0-9 is    "+counter);

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is not understanding when your `for` loop ends. You should add brackets `{ }` around loops and `if` statements, so that only the code inside those brackets executes when the conditions are met.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner variable = new Scanner(System.in);

    int counter = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {   
        int n = variable.nextInt();

        if(0 <= n && n <= 9)
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    variable.close();

    System.out.println("the number of values enterd from 0-9 is: " + counter);
}
```

You should also **close** your `Scanner`.

Short [**tutorial on loops**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm).